Unable to boot pi 5 from USB with NVMe installed
I recently got a pi 5 8GB and also bought a case and an NVMe hat and active cooler and stuff, and I cannot boot it up. I didn't have a way to flash Raspberry Pi OS onto the NVMe, so I used the pi imager to put the OS onto a USB to boot from. Won't work. It tried booting from the NVMe after attempting the microSD option, but it wouldn't boot from USB. I re-flashed the image on the USB and selected the boot order to start with USB (actually NVMe/USB as that was the only option), but still got nothing. It just kept trying to detect the NVMe and micorSD. I even tried disconnecting the NVMe but that didn't work either.
I know I shoulda just got the microSD with the OS on it, but I didn't want it - I want to use the NVMe. I don't have a way (or know of an alternate way) to flash the NVMe with the OS. Thanks in advance 

Welcome. "It just kept trying to detect the NVMe and micorSD..." -> Is that an assumption or is there something that happens which makes you believe this?

No it kept cycling through trying to find something to boot off of and kept returning "failed" or "no" - something along those lines. I attempt again this evening and add pics or a quick video. I should've done that to start, sorry about that.

Added a photo of what I'm seeing when I turn the pi on.

If you can boot from usb or microsd, there are many options to get the pi 5 to boot from ncme drive. First make sure that dtparam=pciex1 (or dtparam=nvme) is in /boot/firmware/config.txt file, a reboot to make it active. The best way is to run the rpi-imager on the nvme drive and then power off, remove the usb and/or microsd and power on.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
